# PySide Button Auto Repeat doesn't start until mouse is moved

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have a PySide application with a single button that implements auto-repeat. But the auto-repeat functionality doesn't seem to be working correctly.

If I simply click and hold the button, its function is only called once no matter how long I wait or what the auto-repeat settings are. But as soon as I move the mouse, the button's functionality is called repeatedly, just as it should be.

This is with Python 2.6, PySide 1.1.2, running on Windows 7 64 bit.

```
self.btn.setAutoRepeat(True)
self.btn.setAutoRepeatDelay(200)
self.btn.setAutoRepeatInterval(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem using normal QT4.x on linux. The issue was that something was connected to the clicked signal. I think it was stealing/changing the focus of the mouse. I just changed that item to connect to the the released signal. That doesn't mean you can't connect to clicked, but just be sure that there are no focus stealing side-effects.